# How to conditionally change text color in Android?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I am making an app that displays information to the user. There are certain parameters that the values of the information should be in. If there is an error, they might not be within those parameters. If the value is not within those parameters, I would like the color of the text to be red (signifying error). If the numbers are getting close to being incorrect, I would like the text to be yellow (Signifying warning). Finally, if the information is correct I want the text to be green. Is it possible to conditionally color the associated text?

I have tried using an `if` statement in my primary `.java` file that uses `tvSteamTemp.setTextColor(R.color.RED);`. When I do this, it says that it "cannot resolve symbol 'color'."

I have also tried using the hexadecimal value for red in the same line of code as above, replacing it for the `R.color.RED`. This came back with the same error: saying "cannot resolve symbol '#FF0000'."

This is what I was thinking the code would look like. When I researched it, this seemed like the way people were saying to go, they just didn't have the right code to set the text color.

```
    if(212 > steamTemp){
        ***Code to set color to red here***
    }else if(235 >= steamTemp && 212 <= steamTemp){
        ***Code to set color to yellow here***
    }else if(235 < steamTemp){
        ***Code to set color to green here***
```

If the steamTemp variable is below 212 degrees Fahrenheit, the textView for that is red. If it is between 212 and 235, it is yellow. If it is above 235, it is green. I think I should be able to figure out the condition statement as it should be basic programming, I just don't know how to set the color from within the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your color: `#FF0000` is defined in `colors.xml`

```
steamTemp.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nameOfYourColor));
```

Or use Android pre-defined colors:

```
steamTemp.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
```

Comment: yupi getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark) is deprecated since android 6.0 so you should use ContextCompact.getColor(getContext(),R.color.your_color_code)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

On the ifs, you can try

```
if (steamTemp < 212) {
    // red
} else if (steamTemp <= 235) {
    // yellow
} else {
    // green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple, look at Android's [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color) class:

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//or
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

or color from resource:

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourDeclaredColor));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gone though each answer above

i would suggest don't use

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_code)
```

Now its **deprecated** since android 6.0 (API 22+) so you should use:

```
tv.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.your_color_code,theme));
```

OR **Context Compat** class for that

```
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.your_color_code));
```